# Need Advice For Using Firebase Features For Android Project

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I need advice for using Firebase in my Android project. I am going to add Sign-in with firebase. In, Registration users must add name, email, password, PayPal, and Referral No and in login, they should enter via email and password. And also I have 2 data which are integers to save during my project. So, I am going to save all of them in firebase. I read that Sign-in with firebase but you can enter only email, password, and name, but what about the rest of my data. Should I use a Firebase Realtime database for them or for all of them? I am having this structure. Please give me some instructions. I am not asking about code just which firebase features should I use to achieve smth like that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can use custom claims with any database moreover firebase user object can bear some data. read the docs there is everything you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I read that Sign-in with Firebase but you can enter only email, password, and name.

Yes, that correct. That's the minimum data that is needed for the authentication process.

> Should I use the Firebase Realtime Database for them or for all of them?

Yes, you can use [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) or even better, [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) to host the rest of the user's data. To distinguish the data between users, remember to use the UID that comes from the authentication process.

Answer (score 0):

You should use firebase realtime or firesore to store other data